# how to change setting for automatic shut down?

Tags: 10.04

I want my server system to be kept on for always. I don't want it to shut down automatically. What is the setting commands for it? 
My server version is 10.04.4

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't shut down automatically by default, meaning you've done something to make it shut down... That makes the next step rather circular. Any idea what you did?

Comment: i did nothing. As it's a server, so i just want it to be on for always so i can even have remote access.. means i may be working after gap of 5-10 hours.

Comment: What I'm saying is it *should* be on. If it's turning off, something has been done to it in order to turn it off after a period of time.

Comment: my server is on right now.. i am leaving from the place where server is placed. i just want that it doesn't shut down itself automatically because of no activity for hours.. i may be remote assessing it after 10 hours..

Comment: This is very strange. I don't know any server installation that does this.

Comment: some addon packages do it - so how's about stop arguing over what someone did and say how to undo it.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons for a computer to shutdown, and I can quickly identify 4:

1. There is a process (or cron job) shutting it down;
2. Power outage, abnormal shutdown;
3. Power outage, gracefull shutdown by your UPS;
4. Hardware failure.

You can see the reason for the shutdown with this command:

```
sudo last -x
```

This command is used to list all system loggins, but it also displays the shutdown, reboot and boot times.

When you shutdown your computer, the run level changes to zero, so you should see this line:

```
runlevel (to lvl 0)
```

If you don't see it, then it's an abnormal shutdown (power outage), and that means you should install an [UPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply).

Answer (score 0):

It's a hardware or software problem. If your server is too hot or defective it may do an emergency shutdown after a while to prevent damage.
Use from a console `less /var/log/syslog` and `dmesg` (the last in pipe with `grep`) to find the reason for the shutdown.
If it's NOT an hardware problem (eg. no kernel warnings) then watch in those places (with `ls` for dirs and `nano` to edit files) to find shutdown commands & remove them (interpret * as a wildcard please):

- /etc/init/
- /etc/init.d/
- /etc/rc.local
- /etc/rc*.d

(if you find "bad" commands here your system might have been violated, it's not a standard behaviour).
If you use cron (installed by default), see here:

- /etc/cron.*
- /etc/crontab

The cron's places may vary depending on your configuration.
(if you find bad stuff here, watch for bad packages or intrusions)
**Important note**: you should not edit cron's files manually, but use a specific software if you can.
If you feel that your system has been haltered or violated reinstall it (do a backup first) OR try to use an Open Source antivirus solution (some malware/virus/backdoor/rootkit can infect Linux!).
If you still can't solve (bad situation) and don't want to reinstall, use `sudo update-rc.d ENTRY disable` to disable the non exential software, but first try to boot in single use mode to see if it's an internal problem.
It's all I can suggest for now, I've done my best.
Try to solve & have a good experience.